Do i have to do restart the audit daemon manually after fedora regular update?
While regular updating (not version upgrade) my fedora 39 system via dnf update this error message appeared.
  Ausgeführtes Scriptlet: audit-3.1.5-1.fc39.x86_64                                                                                       122/296 
Warning: The unit file, source configuration file or drop-ins of auditd.service changed on disk. Run 'systemctl daemon-reload' to reload units.
Stopping logging: 
Warning: The unit file, source configuration file or drop-ins of auditd.service changed on disk. Run 'systemctl daemon-reload' to reload units.

Still the update went successfully,so i restarted my system.
Having no clue about auditctl i just checked for -help and some report.
$ sudo auditctl -s
enabled 1
failure 1
pid 1077
rate_limit 0
backlog_limit 64
lost 0
backlog 0
backlog_wait_time 60000
backlog_wait_time_actual 0
loginuid_immutable 0 unlocked

It lists some "failure". Yet i assume if its some daemon that the daemon restarts itself on booting my system. So no need for 'systemctl daemon-reload' after i restarted my system. Am i right or should i do this manually (and following the fedora docs)?
https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/fedora-coreos/audit/

As you have restarted the system, there is no need to run any systemctl daemon-reload.
You can still check the status of auditd service with systemctl status auditd
